# How to let .NET know that I have an instance of the right class?

Tags: vb.net, class, templates

Let's suppose I have a

```
Class ViewerManager(Of ViewTable)
```

and inside that I have a

```
Protected ReadOnly Property StoredView As ViewTable
```

which has a `Get` inside which I have something like this

```
#Region "View Object Properties"

    Enum ViewerManagerTemplate
        Unkown = 1
        TblMemorizedFilterPage = 2
        TblMemorizedAEV = 3
    End Enum

    Protected _ManagerTemplate As ViewerManagerTemplate = ViewerManagerTemplate.Unkown
    Protected ReadOnly Property ManagerTemplate As ViewerManagerTemplate
        Get
            If _ManagerTemplate = ViewerManagerTemplate.Unkown Then
                If PageID > 0 Then
                    _ManagerTemplate = ViewerManagerTemplate.TblMemorizedFilterPage
                Else
                    _ManagerTemplate = ViewerManagerTemplate.TblMemorizedAEV
                End If
            End If
            Return _ManagerTemplate
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected InitializedStoredView As Boolean = False
    Protected _StoredView As ViewTable = Nothing
    Protected ReadOnly Property StoredView As ViewTable
        Get
            If Not InitializedStoredView Then
                InitializedStoredView = True
                Select Case ManagerTemplate
                    Case ViewerManagerTemplate.TblMemorizedFilterPage
                        If PageObject.StoredViewID > 0 Then
                            _StoredView = CType(CType(BOs.CustomGridBO.GetMemorizedFilterPage(PageObject.StoredViewID), Object), ViewTable)
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
            Return _StoredView
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region
```

Here, at the line of

```
_StoredView = CType(CType(BOs.CustomGridBO.GetMemorizedFilterPage(PageObject.StoredViewID), Object), ViewTable)
```

I know for sure that the `BOs.CustomGridBO.GetMemorizedFilterPage` will return a `TblMemorizedFilterPage` instance and I know for sure that if this line is executed, then `ViewTable` is `TblMemorizedFilterPage` as well, therefore the double `CType` seems to be an overkill for me. Can I simplify this somehow?

EDIT:

Since there was a confusion in the comment section, I think I need to give further information. `TblMemorizedFilterPage` and `TblMemorizedAEV` are both classes and the enum values having the same name are named after these classes.

Comment: What's the returned value of GetMemorizedFilterPage?

Comment: It returns a TblMemorizedFilterPage instance and _StoredView is an instance of ViewTable, which in this case means TblMemorizedFilterPage.

Comment: TblMemorizedFilterPage is a value in an enum. If GetMemorizedFilterPage returns an enum, that's why you can't cast directly to ViewTable.

Comment: TblMemorizedFilterPage is a value in an enum, but it is also the name of a class. When I refer to "instance of TblMemorizedFilterPage" I refer to objects instantiated, having the class of TblMemorizedFilterPage. But I can rename the enum values in this question if they are confusing for you.

Comment: Does the class TblMemorizedFilterPage inherits (or implement) ViewTable?

Comment: ViewTable is a name of a template. When I instantiate ViewerManager, I will essentially instantiate a ViewerManager(Of TblMemorizedFilterPage) or a ViewerManager(Of TblMemorizedAEV). So ViewTable will either be a TblMemorizedFilterPage of a TblMemorizedAEV.

Comment: I understand now what ViewTable represent. If the return value of GetMemorizedFilterPage is TblMemorizedFilterPage how can it also return a TblMemorizedAEV? Unless TblMemorizedAEV inherits from TblMemorizedFilterPage.

Comment: No, another function is used for TblMemorizedAEV, there is no direct, nor transitive inheritance between TblMemorizedFilterPage ant TblMemorizedAEV, they are two classes, completely independent from each-other. The function used for TblMemorizedAEV is called BOs.AEVBO.GetActiveMemorizedAEV. If you think it improves the question, I can add more parts of the code, my intention was to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice, when ViewTable will be a TblMemorizedAEV. Then that line will look like.

```
_StoredView = CType(CType(BOs.CustomGridBO.GetMemorizedFilterPage(PageObject.StoredViewID), Object), TblMemorizedAEV)
```

Since you can't cast a TblMemorizedFilterPage to a TblMemorizedAEV. Your only option is to trick the compiler by casting it to an Object first. Which is the only base class in common with each other.

If you have a lot of If statement, I would think of having two classes with Class ViewerManager(Of ViewTable) as the base class. The sub class would handle those specific situation.

I also find it strange that the template Type is dependent on the enum but the enum isn't based on the template Type. What is you do ViewerManager(Of TblMemorizedAEV) and the PageID is greater than 0.

Comment: I do not need to convert TblMemorizedFilterPage to TblMemorizedAEV and vice versa. When I intend to convert my object from ViewTable to TblMemorizedFilterPage, then ViewTable is a TblMemorizedFilterPage. When I intend to convert ViewTable to TblMemorizedAEV, then ViewTable is a TblMemorizedAEV; PageID is a property which is not applicable if we have a TblMemorizedAEV, so it is equivalent to the solution describe for the other question for now and was used as a second best due to the fact that I was not aware of the possibility to combine GetType and Is, see my other question.

Comment: @LajosArpad yes, this is what you want to do. But that's not how the compiler sees it. The compiler think you want to convert from one to the other, that's why you need to convert to a base object first.

Comment: The compiler cannot see it that way, since when I want to convert a TblMemorizedFilterPage impersonated as ViewTable, then TblMemorizedAEV is completely out of business. In this case the compiler wants to convert ViewTable to TblMemorizedFilterPage and even though ViewTable means the same as TblMemorizedFilterPage in this case, the compiler does not know about the situation, hence I had a problem, solved by upcasting to Object and then downcasting to the desired type. I wonder whether there is a simpler solution, involving something like DynamicCast or the like.